# Flutter- Listview''s children during scroll goes behind above widget

Tags: flutter, user-interface

[Refer this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXbY6SNXirLQNTBtZT4vowdCzBSKarm_/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code it simple use of listView builder.After scroll list view is goes unexpectedly goes behind above row widget.Any suggestion to which widget should use instead listView builder?

```
 Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Sorted By',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
                          color: AppColors.labelText, fontSize: 14),
                    ).paddingForOnly(right: 20),
                    sortButtons()
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  'List of Report',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .bodyText1
                      ?.copyWith(color: AppColors.profileLabel),
                ).paddingForOnly(top: 30, bottom: 10),
                Flexible(
                    child: 
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                              onTap: () {
                                Application.customNavigation(
                                    context: context,
                                    path: ReportDetailScreen.route);
                              },
                              tileColor: AppColors.listTileBG,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                              leading: Image.asset(AssetsPath.calendarSymbol),
                              title: Text(
                                'Monday, Aug 05',
                                style: textTheme.bodyText2?.copyWith(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ).paddingWithSymmetry(vertical: 4))),
                //Expanded(child: reportList(context))
              ],
            ),
```

Thank YOU

Comment: that seems very strange behaviour to me. I wonder if it's a bug in flutter actually. A workaround might be to wrap the widgets above the listview in a container with background color so you at least don't see it.

Comment: Yes @IvoBeckers But i my case i need to wrap material widget to every list item. isn't it bad idea?

Comment: You can try to only just wrap the ListView with Material. I think that would be enough

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is normal, since the only Widget that is scrollable is your `ListView.builder`. To make everything else also scrollable, you can use [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html). Wrap it around your `Column`, which makes the whole `Column` scrollable.
Important to mention is that you have to set [shrinkWrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) property of `ListView.builder()` to `true`, otherwise you'll get an error.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      ...,
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        ...
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe OP's issue isn't that the other widgets don't scroll along, they are supposed to be fixed at the top. The issue is that that the list view scrolls behind those widgets. Which actually seems weird behaviour to me to since the listview is supposed to start below those widgets

Comment: @IvoBeckers true, i too agree

Comment: Oh my bad, I understood it wrong